# Object not defined on one machine but works on another

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

a friend and I are working on a project together and we just merged but for some reason the code below works fine on his but when I run it on mine it can not find any of the variables. Below are the front end and back end code.
**Front end: (Works fine on his machine)**

```
  <% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) { %>
                  <tr>

                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.firstName + " " +  users[i].local.lastName %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.email %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.role %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.street %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.city %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.state %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.zip %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.phone %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%= users[i].local.contract %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="background-color:rgb(4,148,74);font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;font-size:16px;"><a href="/editUser/<%=users[i]._id%>"> Edit Info </a></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <%}%>
```

**Backend:**

```
router.get('/adminUserList', isLoggedIn, isRole, function(req, res) {
  db.collection('users').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.render('adminUserList.ejs', {
      users: results,
      user: req.user
    });
console.log(results);
```

});
});

Again it works fine when we run it on his, but when I run it on mine it cannot find any of the userList[i] items. But when I console.log the results from the backend it returns all users.

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
ypeError: C:\School\final\CS-490-3DPrinting\views\adminUserList.ejs:75
    73| 
    74|                         <td>
 >> 75|                           <%= users[i].local.firstName + " " +  users[i].local.lastName %>
    76|                         </td>
    77|                         <td>
    78|                           <%= users[i].local.email %>
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Or do you even get an error and its just rendering as if it has no users?

Comment: @samanime I apologize, I forgot to add in the error, I have now edited the question with the error.

Comment: It looks like you are referring to "userList", but your examples refer to "users". Did it change and you are somehow pointing at an old (or maybe new) one?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I copied the error as we were changing stuff so it was the wrong thing. Should be fine now, still having the same issue.

Comment: Are you performing any kind of transpilation (Babel, Rollup, Webpack, etc)? Usually these types of "works on my machine" issues stem from something funky in your build pipeline.

Comment: Did you get it working? What was the issue?